# why my onCreate is always triggered when I back to a fragment using Android Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am new in Android development, especially using navigation component. I move from one destination (fragment A) to another destination (fragment B) using code like this

```
val BDestination = AFragmentDirections.actionToB(userData)
findNavController().navigate(BDestination)
```

and when I back from fragmentB to fragment A, the `onCreateView` method in fragmentA is always triggered. I expect if I am back from B to A, then it will not triggered `onCreateView` method and it will only trigger `onResume` method in fragmentA

is it a normal behaviour ? can I change that ? because all the properties in my fragmentA will be gone if `onCreateView` method is called.

Comment: Just confirm that it is onCreate() that is firing and not onCreateView?

Comment: @JamesPalfrey my bad, I mean `onCreateView`

Comment: Answer below :)

Comment: Note: Fragments automatically save and restore your data (same as with a configuration change or process death and recreation), so any state you're losing is due to your code. I'd suggest asking separate questions for each piece of state you're having trouble saving and restoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the lifecycle below, you'll see that once you move away from the activity the view is destroyed via the `onDestroyView()` method however,the moment you go back to it, it fires the `onCreateView()` method.  This is normal behaviour for a fragment lifecycle. If you have code that you don't wish to run everytime the view is brought to the forefront then i would suggest you put them in a boolean if() block.

[image]

Comment: Yes, `onDestroyView()` is called.